# Android: How to add the primary id when using a constructor?

Tags: android

I am trying to let a user add things to my database, and have the main information being added fine, but I can't seem to get the ID field to work correctly, this is what i have so far:

(DatabaseHandler class)

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENTS + "("
            + ST_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + ST_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + ST_SURNAME + " TEXT," + ST_SCHOOL + " TEXT,"
            + ST_READING_LEVEL + " TEXT," + ST_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Constructor i'm using in my StudentProfile class:

```
public StudentProfile(int id String firstName, String surname, String school, String age){
    this._id = id;
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._surname = surname;
    this._school = school;
    this._age = age;
}
```

and in my MainList class:

```
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //int id = StudentProfile.setID();
                String firstName_str = firstName.getText().toString();
                String surname_str = surname.getText().toString();
                String school_str = firstName.getText().toString();
                String age_str = firstName.getText().toString();
                /// LOOK HERE AGAIN
                StudentProfile newProfile = new StudentProfile(id, firstName_str, surname_str, school_str , age_str); 
                db.addStudentProfile(newProfile);
```

Basically what I'm looking for is how to get the ID to be added automatically/called?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for something like an orm mapper, check out: http://greendao-orm.com/

Comment: You are using `AUTOINCREMENT` for id field in database. Don't pass this in your insert query and it should work fine.